# iOS Quick Action Icons in toolbar?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

Quick Action Icons vs Tab Bar Icons vs Navigation Bar and Toolbar Icons 
https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/system-icons/

I want to follow apple design guidelines as much as possible. A fairly common usage is a to favorite something. 
So they have a standard icon for tab with favorites (star shape).(Tab Bar Icons) 
But not an icon for the action itself. There is no star shape for the toolbar. (Navigation Bar and Toolbar Icons)

So how is that supposed to work? (overlay a menu?)
Then there is the quick actions which has a star. But can I use them inside the app? I thought they where only for 3D touch on the app icon itself.